# getting wrong values in cuda c programm

Tags: c, cuda

I am trying to simulate matrix multiplication in cuda C. Everything is correct except the output.

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define     N       4
#define TILE_WIDTH 2

__global__ void MatMul(int*A, int* B, int* C) {  

    int sum; 
    int idx = threadIdx.x; 
    int idy = threadIdx.y; 
    int bx = blockIdx.x; 
    int by = blockIdx.y; 
    int k ,uidx , uidy , i; 
    uidx = bx*TILE_WIDTH + idx;
    uidy = by*TILE_WIDTH + idy; 
    sum = 0;


    // Allocating memory in shared memory

    __shared__ int temp1[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];
    __shared__ int temp2[TILE_WIDTH][TILE_WIDTH];

    //copying the data to shared memory 

    for( i =0;i<N/TILE_WIDTH; i++) 
    { 
        temp1[idy][idx] = A[uidy * N + ((i*TILE_WIDTH)+uidx)%N]; 
        temp2[idy][idx] = B[(i*TILE_WIDTH+uidy * N)%N + uidx]; 
        __syncthreads();

        // multiplying matrices in shared memory 

        for(k=0 ; k < TILE_WIDTH;k++) {
            sum = sum + temp1[idy][k]*temp2[k][idx];
        }
    }

    // synchronizing the threads 

    __syncthreads(); 
    C[uidy*N + uidx] = sum;
}

int main( void ) {

    int a[N][N], b[N][N], c[N][N];     //host copies of a,b,c

    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;        //device copies of a,b,c

    // allocate the memory on the GPU
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_a, N * N * sizeof(int) );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_b, N * N * sizeof(int) );
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&dev_c, N * N * sizeof(int) );

    // fill the matrices 'a' and 'b' on the CPU

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j < N; j++) {
            a[i][j] = j+3;
            b[i][j] = i+6;
        }
    }
    //copy above a,b values to device

    cudaMemcpy( dev_a, a, N * N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( dev_b, b, N * N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    // Prepare timer
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    float time;

    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    //start record
    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    // Kernel invocation with N threads 
    dim3 dimGrid(2,2,1); 
    dim3 dimBlock(TILE_WIDTH,TILE_WIDTH,1);
    MatMul<<<dimGrid , dimBlock>>> (dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);

    //stop record
    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

    //this is operation time
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);

    //clean up      
    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);

    //copy result to host
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, N * N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    //output..
    for (int i=0; i < N; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < N; j++)
            printf( "%d ", a[i][j]);
        printf ("  ");
        for (int j=0; j < N; j++)
            printf( "%d ", b[i][j]);
        printf ("  =  ");
        for (int j=0; j < N; j++)
            printf( "%d ", c[i][j]);
        printf ("\n");
    }



    //free the allocated memory in device
    cudaFree( dev_a );
    cudaFree( dev_b );
    cudaFree( dev_c );
    printf("\n multiplication done!!!\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf(" time elapsed in ms=%f\n",time);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my output:

```
3 4 5 6     6 6 6 6         108 108 115 115
3 4 5 6     7 7 7 7         108 108 115 115
3 4 5 6     8 8 8 8         108 108 115 115
3 4 5 6     9 9 9 9         108 108 115 115
```

It is showing wrong values. Please tell me any error in my program. I'm very new to CUDA C.

Comment: where are the equal signs in the output?

Comment: Foo Bah is right.  The output you claim does NOT match the code.  Specifically, the lack of the " = ".  Please show the *actual* output of your program.

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know what is wrong with your program, I think you should be able to diagnose it better using simpler matrices.   Have you tried multiplying two Identity matrices?  Or filled with all 1s.   Repeated tests with various simple matrices should demonstrate how the cells are being combined.

Ultimately, I think you'll find a problem with the way you use TILE_WIDTH, but I cannot be sure.

Comment: thanks..actually i am from electrical background but in my M.Tech. project i am using CUDA C.so please tell me if i want to simulate a 200 by 200 matrix then what should be the values of TILE_WIDTH & dim3 dimGrid()

Answer (score 1):

This should fix it (in the *i* loop):

```
temp1[idy][idx]= A[TILE_WIDTH*(by*N+i) + idx+idy*N];
temp2[idy][idx]= B[TILE_WIDTH*(bx+N*i) + idx+idy*N];
```

Comment: actually i am from electrical background but in my M.Tech. project i am using CUDA C.so please tell me if i want to simulate a 200 by 200 then what should be the values of TILE_WIDTH & dim3 dimGrid() so that i can get minimum multiplication time

Comment: It's been a while since I've used CUDA, so I can't offer you a very specific answer. One thing you can always do is benchmark different tile sizes, which allows you to see which one fits your algorithm and input data size best.

Comment: ok..then suggest me a book for cuda c or any materials which is good & easy to understand

Comment: You can buy some from [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/275-4751265-8568956?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=cuda+programming&x=0&y=0). The [CUDA Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_0/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) is always useful if you want to learn about what you can do in CUDA and how. [Analysis-driven optimization](http://www.nvidia.com/content/GTC-2010/pdfs/2012_GTC2010.pdf) should help with optimizing your code.